# Optimal strategy for a 2 player game

Tags: algorithm

- 2 players A & B are playing a game involving a number *n*
- Player A makes the first move & both players play alternately.
- In each move the player takes the number n,chooses a number *i* such that *2^i < n* and replaces *n* with *k = n - 2^i* iff the number of 1s in the binary representation of *k* is greater than or equal to the number of 1s in the binary representation of *n*
- Game ends when no player can make a move, ie there does not exist such an *i*

For example:

```
n = 13 = b1101
```

Only possible i=1

```
k = n - 2^i = 11 = b1011
```

Again,only possible i = 2

```
k = n - 2^i = 7 = b111
```

Since Player A cant make any more moves, Player B wins

I've deduced that at any step,we can only choose an i,such that there is a 0 at the corresponding position in the binary representation of n.
For Example:
if n=1010010,then i can only be {0,2,3,5}.
But I cant move any further.A minimax algorithm isnt exactly striking me.I would appreciate any help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a "nim" game to me. Could you edit the rules into a bullet list?

Comment: Might do better on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It is much more readable. The whitespace helps, too. (but I still don't seem to grasp it ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser: Could you please let me know what part of the question is not unerstandable so that I may change it

Comment: It is not your fault, it is almost perfect now. I am just not smart enough! ` i such that 2^i < n`, which to mee apeears that you can choose a bit i, not beyond log2(n). Why cannot the first player choose i=2 ? Oops, there I go again: `the number of 1s in n`

Comment: Its because then the number of 1's in the binary representation of k=13-2^2=9 is less than number of 1's in the bnary representation of n=13

Comment: I would 0) start with pencil&paper. Work backwards: 1) find all the winning moves (where no move is possible). 2) build upto the moves that could lead to them, etc. 3) I would start with 8 bits. 4) If the paper is too small: buy more paper. 5) If you run out of money: the problem is hard. Still looks like a "nim" game, though.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming n is not too big, we can use dynamic programming to solve this problem. 
Define an array A[1:n], where A[i] represents whether player i will win on input i.
Let's use the interpretation:

```
   A[i] = 1, if A wins on input i,
   A[i] = 0, if A loses on input i.
```

Now A can be computed bottom-up as follows:

```
A[1] = 0, A[2] = 1.
For j=3:n { 
      Assign A[j] = 1 if there exists a number i such that (A[j-2^i] = 0) AND 
                              (number of 1's in i >=  number of 1's in j)
      Otherwise  Assign A[j] = 0 
}
```

Comment: If n becomes too large say of the order 10^9,would a top down approach work instead of a DP approach.

Comment: If n has many 1's in it's binary representation, a top down approach with memoization is probably much faster than the DP. Otherwise, I would guess that the DP would be faster. Would be interesting to run some tests to see which is better.